# Nesting ui-view's in Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, pug

main.jade (relevent part)

```
div(ui-view="core")
```

partials/dashboard.jade

```
#dashboard(ng-controller="dashboardController")
    #main-panel(ui-view="mainPanel")
    #side-panel

    nav#top-nav
```

routes.js

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    // loads url from the index
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
        .state('splash', {

        })
        .state('dashboard', {
            abstract: true,
            url:'/dashboard',
            views: {
                'core' : {
                    templateUrl: '/partials/dashboard'
                },
                'mainPanel' : {
                    templateUrl: '/partials/calendar'
                }
            }
        })

}]);
```

Is there a way to render ui-view="core" as well as the ui-view="mainPanel" which is inside core?

For reference, this is how I configured the partials to work with jade

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('main', { 
        title: 'Express' 
    });
});

router.get('/partials/:name', function (req, res) { 
    var name = req.params.name;
    res.render('partials/' + name);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have "nested" ui-views on one level (one state). Because ui-view content is replace by the provided template.
For `mainPanel` to be inside `core` it should be part of a template of a nested state.

```
.state('dashboard.main', {
    url:'/main',
    views: { mainPanel : ... }
}
```

And `dashboard`'s template should contain the `ui-view="mainPanel"`